# Preserve index-string correspondence spark string indexer

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Spark's StringIndexer is quite useful, but it's common to need to retrieve the correspondences between the generated index values and the original strings, and it seems like there should be a built-in way to accomplish this. I'll illustrate using this simple example from the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/ml-features.html#stringindexer):

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "c")],
    ["id", "category"])
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex")
indexed_df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

This simplified case gives us:

```
+---+--------+-------------+
| id|category|categoryIndex|
+---+--------+-------------+
|  0|       a|          0.0|
|  1|       b|          2.0|
|  2|       c|          1.0|
|  3|       a|          0.0|
|  4|       a|          0.0|
|  5|       c|          1.0|
+---+--------+-------------+
```

All fine and dandy, but for many use cases I want to know the mapping between my original strings and the index labels. The simplest way I can think to do this off hand is something like this:

```
   In [8]: indexed.select('category','categoryIndex').distinct().show()
+--------+-------------+
|category|categoryIndex|
+--------+-------------+
|       b|          2.0|
|       c|          1.0|
|       a|          0.0|
+--------+-------------+
```

The result of which I could store as a dictionary or similar if I wanted:

```
In [12]: mapping = {row.categoryIndex:row.category for row in
           indexed.select('category','categoryIndex').distinct().collect()}

In [13]: mapping
Out[13]: {0.0: u'a', 1.0: u'c', 2.0: u'b'}
```

My question is this: Since this is such a common task, and I'm guessing (but could of course be wrong) that the string indexer is somehow storing this mapping anyway, is there a way to accomplish the above task more simply?

My solution is more or less straightforward, but for large data structures this involves a bunch of extra computation that (perhaps) I can avoid. Ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Label mapping can extracted from the column metadata:

```
meta = [
    f.metadata for f in indexed_df.schema.fields if f.name == "categoryIndex"
]
meta[0]
## {'ml_attr': {'name': 'category', 'type': 'nominal', 'vals': ['a', 'c', 'b']}}
```

where `ml_attr.vals` provide a mapping between position and label:

```
dict(enumerate(meta[0]["ml_attr"]["vals"]))
## {0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'b'}
```

**Spark 1.6+**

You can convert numeric values to labels using `IndexToString`. This will use column metadata as shown above.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString

idx_to_string = IndexToString(
    inputCol="categoryIndex", outputCol="categoryValue")

idx_to_string.transform(indexed_df).drop("id").distinct().show()
## +--------+-------------+-------------+
## |category|categoryIndex|categoryValue|
## +--------+-------------+-------------+
## |       b|          2.0|            b|
## |       a|          0.0|            a|
## |       c|          1.0|            c|
## +--------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Spark <= 1.5**

It is a dirty hack but you can simply extract labels from a Java indexer as follows:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexerModel

# A simple monkey patch so we don't have to _call_java later 
def labels(self):
    return self._call_java("labels")

StringIndexerModel.labels = labels

# Fit indexer model
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex").fit(df)

# Extract mapping
mapping = dict(enumerate(indexer.labels()))
mapping
## {0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'b'}
```

Comment: Simply `enumerate(indexer.labels())` does not guarantee the same ordering since the stringIndexer by default uses frequency to Index categories

Comment: How does the Pyspark 1.6+ solution present anything different from simply `indexed_df.drop('id').distinct().show()`... `category` and `categoryValue` are the same